# Equal line height with Libertinus Math?

Tags: math-mode, luatex, libertinus

This inline formula increases the line height. How to prevent?

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setmainfont[Numbers=Lining, Ligatures={Common,TeX}]{Libertinus Serif}

\setsansfont[Numbers=Lining, Ligatures={Common,TeX}]{Libertinus Sans}

\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}

\begin{document}
\blindtext $\text{get}_{gst}$ \blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can either `\smash{}` the math or else use the `setspace` package to slightly increase the line spacing.

Comment: `get\textsubscript{\textit{gst}} `.  It doesn't make much sense to enter math only to quit it again.

Comment: You can do `\text{gst}{}_{gst}`, but there's something hairy going on.

Comment: @egreg Reported: https://tug.org/pipermail/luatex/2018-September/006938.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LuaTeX takes the subscript drop parameter from the font and it turns out that this is much too large.  Luckily you can override it.  Here I set it to 0.5pt, which is the value used by pdfTeX.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\setmainfont[Numbers=Lining, Ligatures={Common,TeX}]{Libertinus Serif}

\setsansfont[Numbers=Lining, Ligatures={Common,TeX}]{Libertinus Sans}

\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}
\AtBeginDocument{$\global\Umathsubshiftdrop\textstyle=.5pt$}

\begin{document}
\blindtext $\text{get}_{gst}$ \blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @KhaledHosny This should be the actual answer to the question.  Thanks for your effort!